# Am I allowed to use other q and a sites?

Tags: support

I'm just curious if like, for example I was trying to answer a story-id question, am I allowed to use other q and a cites to find an answer to the question I'm trying to answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Yes.**

All content posted on Stack Exchange is licensed under the Creative Commons Share Alike 3.0 license, which means that you can use the content with [proper attribution](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/06/25/attribution-required/).

So as long as you're not just word-for-word copy-pasting questions to somewhere else, that's fine.

Aside from that, it's perfectly acceptable and even encouraged to use other sites as sources. Just keep in mind the [guidelines for referencing](https://literature.stackexchange.com/help/referencing), and you should be fine with getting an answer elsewhere and then using that as a source for an answer here. Make sure that you're not just reposting what they wrote here; elaborate, explain more, add sources, include your own work...

As an aside - linking people here from other sites, especially if they could answer a question, is a great way to drive traffic, and you can even win [badges](https://literature.stackexchange.com/help/badges/61/publicist) for driving people here using the "share" link on the bottom of every post (in the format `https://literature.stackexchange.com/[a or q]/[post id][your user id]`). Just make sure that the people you're driving here are at least nominally aware of how the site is different from standard internet forums - linking them to the [tour](https://literature.stackexchange.com/tour) or [How to Answer](https://literature.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) can save a lot of time and aggravation on both ends.

Comment: so, i've tried to follow all these guidelines, but just for confirmation is this all right?https://www.reddit.com/r/whatsthatbook/comments/aa2ats/short_story_about_a_man_condemned_to_death/

Comment: Looks okay to me.